# Scrape a page with infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, scroll, infinite-scroll

I am trying to get all products on an e-commerce site, which uses infinite scroll to load the products, I a found a solution to scroll to the bottom of the page, however, it doesn't seem to have an endpoint, and it keeps going even after it reaches the bottom of the page, so I was wondering how to know if the page has ended so I can put a condition and stop the function clearing the interval, any help is greatly appreciated.
I am pasting my current solution which scrolls down to the end of the page but never stops afterward.

```
(function() {
    var lastScrollHeight = 0, count = 0;
    function autoScroll() {
      count++;
      console.log(count);
      var sh = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
      if (sh !== lastScrollHeight) {
        console.log(sh, lastScrollHeight);
        lastScrollHeight = sh;
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = sh;
      }
    }
    var myInterval = window.setInterval(autoScroll, 100);
}())
```

Comment: In human terms, how do you define "the bottom of the page", if it continues to scroll?  Is it just empty or does it repeat the same products again?

Comment: "the bottom of the page" in this case is when there are no more products to be loaded.
it doesn't continue to scroll because there is nowhere to go, but it keeps calling itself nonetheless, it would be nice if it would just stop. so you can still see that because of the console.log(count)

Comment: So you want to `clearInterval()` when `sh === lastScrollHeight`?

Comment: Use a longer interval to periodically check if any new elements were added

Comment: Why do you want to scroll to the bottom of the page anyway? In that case, the whole setup of the page is wrong. Either change how you load the items, or reverse the item list so the "bottom" objects are shown first.

Comment: Also, you scroll a page by using scrollTop(xCoordinate, yCoordinate), and if you want a smooth transition, you don't use setInterval, but requestForAnimationFrame.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are checking to see if the page has actually scrolled, but are never cancelling the `window.setInterval()`

Something like this should work: (Not tested)

```
(function() {
    var lastScrollHeight = 0, count = 0, myInterval = null, failCount = 0;
    function autoScroll() {
      count++;
      console.log(count);
      var sh = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
      if (sh !== lastScrollHeight) {
        console.log(sh, lastScrollHeight);
        lastScrollHeight = sh;
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = sh;
        failCount = 0; // reset the number of failures
      }
      else {
        failCount++; // record that we failed
        if(failCount >= 10) // if we have failed 10 times in a row then exit
          window.clearInterval(myInterval);
      }
    }
    myInterval = window.setInterval(autoScroll, 100);
}())
```

EDIT:
Updated to allow 10 loops with no scrolling occuring before exiting the interval.

Comment: Only issue would be if it takes longer than 100ms to add new content

Comment: Very true - 100ms is probably too fast for this.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but although it does stop, it does so before reaching the end of the scroll.

Comment: Updated to make early exit less likely, tweaking the interval of the duration and the failCount should get it to the bottom, and then exit.